# SELECT WHERE...IN...OBTAINING DUPLICATED IDS

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have following query:

```
SELECT `id_customer`,`club`
FROM `customer`
WHERE `id_customer` IN (
2487,
2347,
2347
)
ORDER BY `id_customer` DESC;
```

And I obtain following results:

```
2487 -> Club A
2347 -> Club B
```

But I need to obtain:

```
2487 -> Club A
2347 -> Club B
2347 -> Club B
```

Because I'm going to copy these data to .csv file.

Could you help to me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because the `IN` clause doesn't match each of the specified criteria individually.  Using `2347` twice will not cause that row to be selected twice.

One way to accomplish this could be to use a temporary table to hold your customer criteria, and then JOIN on that to get the results:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE customerFilter (id_customer INT);

INSERT INTO customerFilter (id_customer) VALUES (2487), (2347), (2347);

SELECT  c.id_customer,
        c.club
  FROM  customer c
    INNER JOIN customerFilter cf ON cf.id_customer = c.id_customer
  ORDER BY c.id_customer DESC;

DROP TABLE customerFilter;
```

This uses the temporary table `customerFilter` to specify each ID that you want to retrieve a customer for.  In this case, because the `INNER JOIN` is used, a row will be matched in `customer` for each row in `customerFilter`, therefore giving the repeated rows you are looking for.

Output:

```
2487   Club A
2347   Club B
2347   Club B
```